# An argument for Array.prototype.includes() (or .indexOf()) that will always return true?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently using the array `includes()` method to filter an object. E.g.

```
products.filter((product) => (
        product.tags.includes(someTag)
))
```

However I'd like there to be some default `someTag` value that always returns true - basically what the default "don't filter" value would be. But I just can't come up with one. The equivalent would be an empty string in `String.prototype.indexOf` but I know of no comparable value.

I certainly could just not call the function at all if someTag is undefined by it's be nice to not have this option. (The dirtiest idea I had was using `product.tags[0]` but that won't work for empty arrays and isn't reusable.)

Ideas? Or is it just not possible.

Comment: I don't see how this would be possible, given that every array you work with could be different.

Comment: What's the usecase for this?

Comment: This isn't real, the question as well isn't real, the thought towards this isn't real. If you want "someTag" then put "someTag" init for it to pass.

Comment: According to [the spec](http://tc39.github.io/Array.prototype.includes/), step 3 is "If len is 0, return false." This happens before the `searchElement` is ever accessed, so no value of `searchElement` can cause `includes` to return `true` for an empty array. Which makes sense because an empty array includes nothing. (This is different from `String.indexOf`, which is a substring search, not a character search.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such value.

Change your function so it checks for the magic value and doesn't call `includes`.

```
products.filter((product) => (
    someTag === undefined || product.tags.includes(someTag)
))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such value.

To not filter the array, don't call `includes`

```
products.filter(product => someTag === specialTag || product.tags.includes(someTag))
```

or swap out the complete predicate function

```
products.filter(someTag === specialTag
  ? product => true
  : product => product.tags.includes(someTag)
)
```

or don't call `filter` at all

```
someTag === specialTag
  ? products
  : products.filter(product => product.tags.includes(someTag))
```